# YA(?) book with crab-like aliens

Tags: story-identification, books

This may be a YA book, probably from the early 2000s.

Crab-like aliens have turned earth into a hellhole simply by buying it for worthless alien "baubles".

The protagonist was a young guy who, I think, wanted a gaming console that plugged into the brain?

There was a floating city and in the end he plugs into a spaceship from a different alien species, buried under ice, to shoot down the bad aliens' ship in orbit.

Comment: This sounds like the situation in Somtow Sucharitkul's _Mallworld_.